# How to access last element in a web page when everything has the same class?

Tags: python, selenium

I doubt I made myself clear on the question, but I want to get the last message sent by a person on Discord (via web). The problem is that, when using web inspector for trying to get a unique attribute of the message, I noticed that every other single message has the same class, and there is no other attribute (like class, id, etc) that I can use. I'm new to Selenium and HTML, so I don't know much.

Let's say I have 2 messages. The first says "hello", and the second one "bye". When I type this:

```
message = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' markup-2BOw-j containerCozy-336-Cz markupRtl-3M0hmN ')]")
```

I get "hello", because both messages share the same class `markup-2BOw-j containerCozy-336-Cz markupRtl-3M0hmN`, and apparently the method picks the first one that matches.

I've looked through other similar questions, but the message is unknown so I can't use `contains`, nor `[position()=2]` at the end of the `find_element_by_xpath` method because I don't know the number of the message.

Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: so do all the `div` messages share `markup-2BOw-j containerCozy-336-Cz markupRtl-3M0hmN` text in `@class`?

Comment: Yes, they all share the text@AshmitBhattarai

Comment: Did you use `find_elements_by_xpath` instead?
`message = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' markup-2BOw-j containerCozy-336-Cz markupRtl-3M0hmN ')]")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find_elements_by_xpath` to get a list of all the elements matching the locator and take the last item on that list

```
all_messages = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' markup-2BOw-j containerCozy-336-Cz markupRtl-3M0hmN ')]")
message = all_messages[-1]
```

By the way you can simplify the `xpath` to

```
find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='markup-2BOw-j containerCozy-336-Cz markupRtl-3M0hmN']")
```

Or use `css_selector` instead

```
find_elements_by_css_selector('.markup-2BOw-j.containerCozy-336-Cz.markupRtl-3M0hmN')
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! But why the `all_messages[-1]`? What does the [-1] do to get the last item?

Comment: @Gintade `[-1]` takes the last item of a list in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Use *find_elements_by_xpath* to do this.It will return a list of matching WebElements.After this you can access the last element by using list[-1]

```
message = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='markup-2BOw-j containerCozy-336-Cz markupRtl-3M0hmN']")
print(message[-1].text)
```

[Docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: How is that answer different from mine?

Comment: @Guy my first answer here.There were no answers here while I was writing this.Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use `last()`:

```
message = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' markup-2BOw-j containerCozy-336-Cz markupRtl-3M0hmN ')])[last()]")
```